# SFTP using filezilla

Tags: remote-access, sftp, filezilla

I have bunch of files which I need to transfer to a remote server. The problem is that the remote server is inside a Virtual Machine. So, first I need to access the VM and then I access the remote machine. So, the flow goes like this 
`localhost -> Docker -> remote machine`. How can I transfer the files using Filezilla to the remote machine instead of transferring to the VM first?

Answer (score 0):

The remote machine likely already has a network stack with TCP/IP installed. What you need to do is to expose the remove machine to the 'outside' world.

Maybe you have a virtual network inside the virtual machine. This way, IP addresses are only accessible from within the virtual machine (likely default for Docker).

Your options:

- Configure Docker to use an IP address from your local network rather than to create a virtual network.
- Use SSH to create a tunnel to connect the two networks this way.